Share button not appearing on Photo albums
I have a photo album on Facebook that I want people to be able to share, but the Share option is not available.  The only options I have are Like, Comment and Copy.  I may have turned off sharing in the past but cannot remember how i did this, and cannot find how to change it.  Any help appreciated

I've been trying to find a solution for a couple of years. A workaround is to share the URL copied from the browser's address bar while you have the Facebook album open.
